# TimeSpan remove seconds

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, datetime, timespan

How do you truncate the seconds bit from a timespan object in C#? i.e. 15:37

I'm outputting a timespan object to JavaScript in the format of HH:mm and kind of want the server side to process providing the correct format instead of clients browsers, can that be done without providing this as a C# string object to JavaScript?

Comment: If you're formatting the timespan as HH:mm aren't the seconds already truncated?

Comment: Do you really want to set the seconds to 0 in a TimeSpan, or just omit them when converting to string?

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338658/can-you-round-a-net-timespan-object/338705#338705

Comment: @CodeInChaos @fredrik-mork @Nick Yes omit the seconds without converting to string, my JSON serializer will need to get hh:mm in TimeSpan format without converting to String

Comment: @Maya: a `TimeSpan` is a value, not a string representation of a value. If you need it in a specific format, you will need to convert it to a string.

Comment: So perhaps the real question is: "How do I add a raw string when serializing to json without the serializer automatically quoting the string."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can truncate the 'ticks' value which is the core of a TimeSpan:

```
TimeSpan t1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(1.551);
Console.WriteLine(t1);
TimeSpan t2 = new TimeSpan(t1.Ticks - (t1.Ticks % 600000000));
Console.WriteLine(t2);
```

Gives:

```
01:33:03.6000000
01:33:00
```

Comment: Thanks but I need 01:33 output in my case

Comment: @Maya "1:33" is a string. You just said you wanted a TimeSpan and not a string.

Comment: Then you need to send a preformatted string, not a TimeSpan.  I read the question has 'how do I do this without sending a string', sorry.

Comment: @CodeInChaos @will-dean thanks Will I thought there is a way to produce the hh:mm format AS a TimeSpan without converting to String.

Comment: @Maya I think you're going to have to either modify your JSON serializer or do this on the client side. Or just modify the value you're sending to your serializer and send a string instead.

Comment: A TimeSpan has no format. It's just an integral number of ticks. I think what you want is changing how it's serialized to json, and not the TimeSpan itself.

Comment: @Maya - TimeSpan doesn't have any particular string representation until someone converts it into a string - pretty much all .NET types work like this.  Though you could create one which carried its format with it, that isn't the way the standard types work.

Comment: Ok fair enough, that clears things up for me, many thanks guys, a +1 vote for you all :)

Comment: Great answer, but I would use TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute instead of 600000000.

Answer (score 20):

You can use a format string for that:

```
public string GetTimeSpanAsString(TimeSpan input)
{
    return input.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not optimal, but easy to read:

```
TimeSpan.FromMinutes((long)duration.TotalMinutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
string.Format("{0:H:mm}",myTime)
```

Comment: That code crashes if `myTime` is a `TimeSpan` (*System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.*)

Comment: @Fredrik, sorry, however `H:mm` should be the converter your looking for.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `H:mm` is not a valid [format string for a `TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx). For a `DateTime` yes, but not for `TimeSpan`.

Comment: @Fredrik, I was under the impression that it would parse the string for a time and convert it to the specified format. I apologize for giving you false information.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this. This truncates to minutes using the truncation of an integer division, followed by a multiplication by the divisor.

```
return TimeSpan.FromTicks(input.Ticks/TicksPerMinute*TicksPerMinute);
```