# Formatting a nullable DateTime field in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to change the format of a nullable `datetime` field in a table, so that it displays in the format `ddd dd mmm yyyy`. I have tried using `DateTime.ToString("ddd dd mmm yyyy)`, and `DateTime.Value.ToString("ddd dd mmm yyyy")`, but neither have worked.

```
<td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DailyReportDate)
</td>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: "but neither have worked" doesn't help. What is the expected output, what is the actual output?

Comment: Is it not meant to be ("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy")? and NOT ("ddd dd mmm yyyy")

Comment: "neither have worked" - please give the *exact* problems. Wrong values? No values? Compile-time failure? Note that `m` means minute, not month. Perhaps you just wanted `MMM`? If you'd explained the symptoms in your questions, we'd know...

Comment: Why don't you just do `<td>@item.ToString("some format string")</td>`?

Comment: WHen I use the ToSTring method it gives the error "Method ToSTring has 0 parameters but is invoked with 1 argument". I think this is because it is a nullable DateTime, as opposed to a DateTime, but I don't know how to get round this

Comment: This should work -> item.Value.ToString("ddd dd mmm yyyy) (checked). Are you sure that type is "DateTime?"?

Comment: Yeah it's definietly DateTime:         public Nullable<System.DateTime> DailyReportDate { get; set; }

Comment: When I try to use item.Value it gives the error: Cannot resolve symbol 'Value'

Comment: That's because you need to use: item.DailyReportDate.Value.ToString("ddd dd mmm yyyy)

Comment: The code builds now using that, but crashes at that line, throwing the error: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: You're using it wrong. You typed `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DailyReportDate.Value.ToString("format"))`, but should have instead typed `item.DailyReportDate.Value.ToString("format"))` (without `DisplayFor`). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417311/formatting-datetime-error-templates-can-be-used-only-with-field-access-propert) on why does this happen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem here is that the `DateTime?` has no `ToString()` method which accepts formatting string. To overcome this, you can use the following piece of code:

```
@string.Format("{0:ddd dd mmm yyyy}", item.DailyReportDate)
```

If `DailyReportDate` is `null`, then this code will render as an empty string. Otherwise, you get your formatted datetime. This behavior is described in [Nullable.ToString Method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket.aspx)

Hope that helps.

---

Not **exactly** what you want, but this can help you.

If you had a simple `DateTime` (non-nullable), then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679352/converting-datetime-format-using-razor) is a good example on how to accomplish what you want. To summarize, all you need to do is to set a `DisplayFormatAttribute` attribute on your property

```
public class Model {
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMM yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? DailyReportDate { get; set;}
}
```

and then you can use it like pointed out:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(item=> item.DailyReportDate)
```

You can find the documentation for `DisplayFormatAttribute` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

.ToString() always come up with "object reference not set to an instance of an object" as this method required the not null object. You must use the if else like this

```
@if (modelItem => item.DailyReportDate != null)
{
    //add format
}
else
 {
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DailyReportDate)item.Amount)
 }
}
```