# Taking a DateTime and Comparing the Time

Tags: c#, datetime, time, compare

I have a DateTime object with DateTime stored within it.

How would I take that DateTime and compare its time so I can check whether the time within that DateTime is greater, or less than 11:00:00 or 20:00:00 etc?

Comment: What about `.Hour`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`TimeOfDay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you can use;

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan timeCheck = (7,0,0)    //07:00 
If(today.TimeOfDay > timeCheck)
{
   //do something
}
```

or you could also use [`Hour`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour(v=vs.110).aspx) that gets the hour component of the date in a way;

```
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    If(today.Hour > 6)
    {
       //do something
    }
```

Comment: This looks like the right thing! My only concern is the timeCheck being (7,0,0) and commented as 7:00PM. How would I change it to AM or PM?

Comment: @Izacch there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044603/convert-time-span-value-to-format-hhmm-am-pm-using-c-sharp

Comment: Many thanks this is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [TimeOfDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
  DateTime source = DateTime.Now;

  if (source.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0) &&
      source.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(20, 0, 0)) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: I've put it just for generalization, when we want to check, say, `11:45` and `20:10`; in this particular case I agree that `source.Hour` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try the DateTime.CompareTo Method (DateTime).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ata5aya(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

```
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        int[] timeOnly = Array.ConvertAll(dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss").Split(':'), int.Parse);
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(timeOnly[0],timeOnly[1],timeOnly[2]);
          if (ts >= new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0) && ts <= new TimeSpan(20, 0, 0)) {
              Console.WriteLine("InBetween");
  }
        else
            Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
```

[Proof of work](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WQCuPL)