# Conversion of TimeSpan to a new variable on HHH: mm

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am downloading the list of times from the database

```
var listaNadgodzinZPoprzMies = _ecpContext.Karta.Where(x => x.Login == userName && x.Rok == numerRoku && x.Miesiac < numerMiesiaca)
                                                            .Select(b => string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.SaldoNadgodzin) ? TimeSpan.Zero : TimeSpan.Parse(b.SaldoNadgodzin))
                                                            .ToList();
```

Adds all times

```
var sumaListaNadgodzinZPoprzMies = listaNadgodzinZPoprzMies.Aggregate(TimeSpan.Zero, (t1, t2) => t1 + t2);
```

And, **I need to convert the number of minutes/** from the variable shown in the image (TimeSpan)

**to string to format HHH:mm** to other new variable

[image]

I scraped out these two functions some time ago in javascript ( I don't know how to convert them to c # ) (I don't know if it will work and whether it will be useful)

```
function msToTime(duration) {
    const minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60), // 3.4 - 3, 3.5 - 3, 3.8 - 3
        hours = Math.floor(duration / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    return twoOrMoreDigits(hours) + ":" + twoOrMoreDigits(minutes);
}

function twoOrMoreDigits(n) {
    return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n; // if (n < 10) { return '0' + n;} else return n;
}
```

anyone have any idea?

Comment: you need convert timeSpan to DateTime  like format 'hh:mm' or any format time ?
if you need this, please see link https://stackoverflow.com/a/13044648/12777835

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(200,1,23);

string strTime = $"{((int)time.TotalHours).ToString("D3")}:{time.Minutes.ToString("D2")}";

Console.WriteLine(strTime);
```

Output:

> 200:01

Answer (score -1):

You want to format a timespan, you can achieve it by using this code:

```cs
var timespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3180);
var result = timespan.ToString("hh:mm");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

hh - hour in 24h format with leading zero
mm - minutes with leading zero

You can read more about timespan formatting here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings

Comment: what is HHH:mm format? please visit the link above for further information

Comment: @krolPodGora I actually gave you a way to do it. The standard timespan doesn't natively support that format.

Comment: and it is possible to draw minutes from timespan and convert it to HHH: mm?

Comment: just use my constructor and @MarcoSalerno strTime

Comment: @Tal it isn't even needed, his variable is already a timespan

Comment: @MarcoSalerno you're correct, he just asked specifically for a new variable