# Round Timespan Seconds

Tags: c#

Round timespan seconds I also need do same with .Hours and .Minutes

This:

```
1.53994 second
```

to:

```
1 second
```

Comment: Wouldn't 1.53994 rounded be 2?

Comment: @Ashkru Did you even bother to look at the answers from the linked post?

Comment: That is to round I was total second it is nothing like my question.

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromSeconds((int)(ts.TotalSeconds));`as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37722864/205233) rounds to full seconds *exactly like your question*.

Comment: @Ashkru I would say edit your question and add the code sample for it so as to benefit the others. Also, please change the rounding of 1.53994 seconds to 2 seconds. Otherwise, the interpretation of the question itself will be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked for me.

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.54);
Math.Round(ts.TotalSeconds);
```