# How to get time difference of two values taken by Winforms DateTimePicker only considering hours minutes and seconds and without miliseconds in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, timespan

I'm getting values from two dateTimePickers and I need to get the time difference between them. Now, I'm calculating the difference using the below code, but I'm getting a wrong time difference with Milliseconds. Is there a way to calculate the time difference without considering Milliseconds.
[WindowsFormScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIJa0.png)

```
TimeSpan difference = dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

*Example 1;*

- Start time          : 4/24/2022 2:30:11 PM
- end time            : 4/24/2022 2:30:11 PM
- Actual difference   : -00:00:00.0049863
- **Expected difference : 00:00:00**

*Example 2;*

- Start time          : 4/24/2022 2:29:01 PM
- end time            : 4/24/2022 10:29:01 PM
- Actual difference   : 07:59:59.9037925
- **Expected difference : 08:00:00**

*Example 3;*

- Start time          : 4/24/2022 4:24:28 PM
- end time            : 4/24/2022 10:30:28 PM
- Actual difference   : 06:05:59.9648821
- **Expected difference : 06:06:00**

It will give expected answers, when I'm retyping the time value in both dateTimePickers in Winform but doesn't work when I didn't retype minutes field in each dateTimePicker.

***I don't want to round up the answers. I want to do the difference calculation without considering milliseconds. So that it will give correct answers for what ever the values we parse for dateTimePickers.***

(I'm a newbie to c#. so I'm sorry if I'm not much clear. Thank you so much!)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I want the exact time difference without considering Milliseconds. So rounding up don't work.

Comment: You said you don't want to round up, but your second example is rounding up?

Comment: I need the time difference with exact hours : minutes: seconds but without considering milliseconds.

Comment: [Custom TimeSpan format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: I'm 99% sure you're intializing one or both of the datetime pickers with DateTime.Now (or something similar) which is the current time INCLUDING milliseconds (even though the picker won't show it). Maybe you're then manually changing the input to some other time (but that keeps the milliseconds in tact). THAT's where the differences in milliseconds comes from. THERE'S your problem. Get rid of the milliseconds there and then your calculations will result in round seconds too, no need for rounding.

Comment: So do this: `var t = DateTime.Now; var now = new DateTime(t.Year, t.Month, t.Day, t.Hour, t.Minute, t.Second);` and then initialise your DateTimePickers to `now`.

Comment: Yes!!! It is 100% correct. Thank you so much @RobIII . I have initialized DateTimePickers as in your code. Then, it worked correctly as expected.

Comment: @JananiBalasooriya It doesn't work as expected if you don't round the result. If you ignore milliseconds, the result might be 1 seconds off.

Comment: @RezaAghaei No because Janani uses [two DateTimePickers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIJa0.png), each not displaying milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
   DateTime adjustedDateTimePicker2 = dateTimePicker2.Value.AddMilliseconds(dateTimePicker2.Value.Millisecond * -1);
        
   DateTime adjustedDateTimePicker1 = DateTimePicker.Value.AddMilliseconds(dateTimePicker.Value.Millisecond * -1);
        
   TimeSpan difference = adjustedDateTimePicker2 - adjustedDateTimePicker1;
```

Comment: Why _should_ this fix it? Please provide detailed information (an explanation) about your approach.

Comment: The code explains this really well, simply read what it does: 
You are simply resetting the milliseconds to zero, so they do not effect your calculation.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried this now. But it doesn't resetting Milliseconds to zero. So, still not giving the expected answer.

Comment: `.AddMilliseconds()` _returns_ the new value, so the current implementation suggestion won't change the `dateTimePicker*.Value` value.

Comment: Answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You may read hours, minutes, and seconds separately:

```
int hourCnt = difference.Hours;
int minuteCnt = diffenrence.Minutes;
int secondCnt = difference.Seconds;
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried your method but it isn't giving the expected answer. If we consider above **Example 2**, it will give 'hourCnt' of 7 and not the expected answer of 8.

Comment: Janani Balasooriya: you add 500 ms to your difference value you should get the values to do expect. Values which differ less then half a second from your expected result will then be rounded up.

Answer (score 0):

You can first [round the timespan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2008570/3110834), then format the result using a [Custom Timespan format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) like `"hh':'mm':'ss"` or `@"hh\:mm\:ss"`:

```
var d1 = DateTime.Parse("4/24/2022 4:24:28 PM");
var d2 = DateTime.Parse("4/24/2022 10:30:28 PM");
var d = d2 - d1;

int precision = 0;
const int TIMESPAN_SIZE = 7;
int factor = (int)Math.Pow(10, (TIMESPAN_SIZE - precision));
TimeSpan roundedTimeSpan = 
    new TimeSpan(((long)Math.Round((1.0 * d.Ticks / factor)) * factor));

MessageBox.Show(roundedTimeSpan.ToString(@"hh':'mm':'ss"));
```

Which shows:

```
06:06:00
```

Comment: Thank you! Formatting the difference won't work. I need to not consider milliseconds so that it doesn't affect the difference calculation.